# System.OutOfMemoryException - Не хватает памяти

Tags: c#, .net, base64

Данный код делает следующие: берёт файл и кодирует в base64 и записывает текст в текст бокс,всё бы нечего но если брать слишком большой файл то будет ошибка **System.OutOfMemoryException** чуть-чуть погуглив я узнал что эта ошибка вызвана из за нехватки памяти(даже самое название ошибки на это намекает),так как я столкнулся с нехваткой памяти первый раз хотел бы увидеть пример решения этой проблемы.

```
            var fB = File.ReadAllBytes(@Filederctoryname);
            string encodedFile = Convert.ToBase64String(fB);
            richTextBox1.Text = encodedFile;
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Если вам таки необходимо добавить base64 этого файла в текстбокс - придётся добавить памяти) Но можно читать/отображать по частям.

Comment: А на сколько файл большой? Так-то если собрать программу в X64, то ошибка вылетать не должна, так как должен вступить файл подкачки.

Comment: А зачем пользователю видеть большой файл в виде base64? Покажите ему, например, сообщение: "Операция успешно завершена". Или небольшой кусочек этого base64. | А, разглядел, до этого даже не доходит.

Comment: Выход напрашивается сам собой: написать свой вариант этого метода, который будет писать не в строку, а прямо в поток (файл). И читать он может тоже напрямую из потока (файла). Код можно подсмотреть в https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Convert.ToBase64String

Comment: Ничего удивительного. В .NET размер выходной строки будет в 1,5 раза больше исходного массива из-за 2-ух байтового char'а. А с учётом ограничения на размер объекта в 2Гб выходит, что массив более ~1,3 Гб ты попросту не закодируешь в .NET. Так что, как советуют - пиши реализацию, которая напрямую с входным/выходным потоками работает, но вот зачем тебе Base64 для таких огромных файлов - вопрос хороший...

Comment: @John лимит на размер массива легко отключается опцией в конфиге :)

Comment: @vp_arth ты уверен? Если я не ошибаюсь, то там только какая-то тема со сборкой мусора.